# Input doesn't show the initial values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a constant which has initial value

```
const [userProfileDataFetched, setUserProfileData] = useState('')
```

The initial value of above needs to be set to another const :

```
const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({
        name: {
            value: userProfileDataFetched.name, //Issus here: This is initial value right, this should change later ? If i write it like value= "some text" it works. This doesn't work
            validation: ['blank', 'name'],
            errorMsg: nameErrorMsg,
            errorKey: 'ename',
        }
```

Here's the text input:

```
<TextInput
                        placeholderTextColor={errors.ename ? ThemeColors.themeRed : ThemeColors.darkGrey}
                        
                        style={styles.input}
                        name={lang.name}
                        value={profileData.name.value}
                        onChangeText={text =>
                            setProfileData({
                                ...profileData,
                                ...{
                                    name: {
                                        value:text, //UPDATED
                                        validation: ['blank', 'name'],
                                        errorMsg: nameErrorMsg,
                                        errorKey: 'ename',
                                    },
                                },
                            })
                        }
                    />
```

Comment: It seem like you are confusing setting the initial value of a state with altering the state. As the name implies, the initial value can only be set once, namely inside the the `useState` call. What you probably want to ask is: "How can I update the state with this specific value?"
Now, inside your code you have hidden a comment that indicates that you know how to update the state and that your actual question is how to obtain the updated value of the `TextField` component, is that right?

Comment: initial visible value should be userProfileDataFetched.name
Then, I should be able to change it to xyz
this is profile update page where name input is coming from backend(userProfileDataFetched.name), which is iniitally visible. Then, the state of main input field needs to be changed onChange event. How do we acheive that as it takes the value and doesn't change as the state should be updated on change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React Native, changed text is passed as a single string argument to the callback handler.  So, instead of doing
`onChangetext={e=>console.log(e.target.value}`
you would do
`onChangetext={value=>console.log(value}`.

Comment: i have used {e.target.value} multiple times but on single parameter like 
const [name, setName] = useState('');
But in the above Problem Statement, 
1. I have name inside of profileData
2. The initial value has to be taken from another state's value.

Comment: you have a string set for profileData.name.value initial state.  Use a variable in useState if you want to set it to something else that you are passing in.

Comment: Updated the query for clear understanding , your answer did help in one thing, but setState isn't updating the initial values if I add above

Comment: tried doing that in useState only " userProfileDataFetched.name" but dint work